# php fatal error unable to read when i want to composer install

Tags: php, symfony

When i run composer install or update :

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the "/home/marc/Desktop/colcot/colcot-2022/Colcot/.env" environment file. in /home/marc/Desktop/colcot/colcot-2022/Colcot/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:569
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 /home/marc/Desktop/colcot/colcot-2022/Colcot/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(92): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->doLoad()
!!  #1 /home/marc/Desktop/colcot/colcot-2022/Colcot/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(114): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->load()
!!  #2 /home/marc/Desktop/colcot/colcot-2022/Colcot/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(157): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->loadEnv()
!!  #3 /home/marc/Desktop/colcot/colcot-2022/Colcot/vendor/symfony/runtime/SymfonyRuntime.php(102): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->bootEnv()
!!  #4 /home/marc/Desktop/colcot/colcot-2022/Colcot/vendor/autoload_runtime.php(23): Symfony\Component\Runtime\SymfonyRuntime->__construct()
!!  #5 /home/marc/Desktop/colcot/colcot-2022/Colcot/bin/console(11): require_once('/home/marc/Desk...')
!!  #6 {main}
!!    throw in /home/marc/Desktop/colcot/colcot-2022/Colcot/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php on line 569
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
```

Im beginner so i don't really know what to do...

I already try to follow this answer https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/issues/345 but i don't know how to do it.

I accept any suggestion ^^ Thanks to help me

*Change

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the "/var/www/.env" environment file. in /var/www/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:569 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(92): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->doLoad(false, Array) #1 /var/www/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(114): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->load('/var/www/.env') #2 /var/www/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(157): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->loadEnv('/var/www/.env', 'APP_ENV', 'dev', Array) #3 /var/www/vendor/symfony/runtime/SymfonyRuntime.php(102): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->bootEnv('/var/www/.env', 'dev', Array) #4 /var/www/vendor/autoload_runtime.php(23): Symfony\Component\Runtime\SymfonyRuntime->__construct(Array) #5 /var/www/public/index.php(5): require_once('/var/www/vendor...') #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php on line 569
```

Comment: So I'm gonna ask the obvious question, does the file `/home/marc/Desktop/colcot/colcot-2022/Colcot/.env` _actually exist?_ It's kind of important for us to know...

Comment: i don't find it so i don't think it exist @M.Eriksson

Comment: Since it seems that it expect it to exist, you need to create it. Are you using symfony, or are you just using their dotenv extension? If you're using symfony, their docs has a lot of info about it. If you're only using symfony's dotenv-extension, then we can't really help much since we don't know what it expects to contain. However, files starting with `.` are usually hidden by default in many OS's so make sure that you can see hidden files when looking for it.

Comment: So the diagnostic message reflects the actual state of the system to the understanding of the user. Why are you concerned then about the message, it looks entirely correct. Why did you hide this fact? What is your real question?

Comment: Im using symfony so i will search for this. Thank you

Comment: `$ touch /home/marc/Desktop/colcot/colcot-2022/Colcot/.env` should create an empty file if it does not exist so far. Then the error should go away, however if the project is not yet configured to your needs, you will see other errors. At least you know the location of the .env file then ;)

Comment: When i go to 127.0.0.1 i got an error from vendor so it's from composer ? @hakre

Comment: @Aika: Hard to say, very likely not, because in vendor you just have all vendored PHP files, that is third-party-libraries. Composer is only in use to place the files there, what is done with all those files then is a different story. What you can say is that the overall software configuration has errors. So you need to change the configuration to get it to a working state. But how should that be answered here? Perhaps create a new, second project from scratch and play the installation through again? Disk space normally is cheap. You can then compare.

Comment: idk if it's normal but now i got another error : Environment variable not found: "DATABASE_URL".

Comment: I think i now need to configure all my .env file

Comment: Yes, you have not configured the software project. You know, it requires reading the instructions first. When you were setting up this project, it seems you have missed some steps. Why not start another try in a different directory from scratch? When you found out what is missing there, you can go back to the first project.